# sed reports "unknown command"

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote this:

```bsh
sudo sed -i ‘s/3389/3390/g’ /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

That produced this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'
```

Answer (score 6):

Compare your

```
 sudo sed -i ‘s/3389/3390/g’ /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

vs the correct

```
 sudo sed -i 's/3389/3390/g' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

Check the different type of quotes.

Be careful when copy-pasting from document editors like Writer or  Word, those will often automatically change quotes (and other things) to match your locals.

Comment: thank u.... i been such a fool. Using for the first time, trying to setup... thanks a lot man. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but the cause was different. I did not use the ` character, nor did I copy-paste the code from somewhere. I was writing a sed script with a condition, and used a new line for the command. Posting this here in case someone else has the same problem and wasn't helped by the accepted answer.

Here is how to replicate the error:

```
echo class:myclass > myfile
cat script
/class:/
s/myclass/MYCLASS/g #ctrl+d to exit
sed -f script myfile
```

Output:

```
sed: file script line 2: unknown command: `
'
```

What fixes it is either to place the command after the condition (on the same line), or use curly braces, so that the script looks like this:

```
/class:/ s/myclass/MYCLASS/
```

Or this:

```
/class:/ {
s/myclass/MYCLASS/
}
```